# Simple Jquery animate position on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to Animate a div's top position by -130px, so it will move off screen. Its not working and i cant workout why! Am obviously a jQuery/Javascript novice.

Basically i have a button/hyperlink with the id #NavShrink, on clicking this i want the div #Header to slide up off screen by 130px, leaving its bottom 20px on screen.

Nothing happens!

Here's my code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
color:#7b7a7a;
}


#Header {
height:150px;
background-color:#f4f4e9;
}



#MainNav {
padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;
width:1140px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:right;

position:relative;
height:130px;
}




a#NavShrink {
display:block;
width:15px;
height:15px;
background-image:url(../images/ShrinkNav.png);
position:absolute;
bottom:5px;
right:0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Wrap">
<div id="Header">
    <div id="MainNav">
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $('#NavShrink').click(function() {
            $('#Header').animate({ top: "-=130px"})
            })
            </script>
            <a href="#Shrink" id="NavShrink"></a>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the issue raised by [j08961](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789326/82548), another problem, I imagine, is that you're animating the `top` property; which effectively has no meaning in a `div` (or other element) with `position: static` (the default `position` property).

To animate, simply assign `position: relative` to the relevant `div`.

Brief, though hopefully illustrative, [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K2Jhg/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Either wrap your code in a document ready call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

or put your code at the end of your document, before the closing `</body>` tag. You're executing your code before the element you want it to act on exists.

Also, change your animate call to `$('#Header').animate({ top: "-=130"})` (no px), and give the `#Header` a position (e.g. position:relative).

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mPaTd/)**.

Comment: Bro I reckon he is looking for something like this might be :P - http://jsfiddle.net/EGc96/ or I misunderstood something `:)`

Comment: Cooleos, thanks, sorry - I was reconfirming my own doubt! apology if it cam,e out wrong `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Hey is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/EGc96/

you can also use `.toggle` for slide effect or sliup and down.

hope it fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$('#NavShrink').click(function() {
    $('#Header').animate({
       // top: "-=130",
        height: "-=130"
    });
});​
```